# Multi user chat is not working on server

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

Using smack API,openfire and XMPP i had created chat application in android.
In that i added group chat functionality.But on my local server it work's fine but when i am trying to run on server first time it runs then it gives error like:

```
04-25 06:40:02.362: W/System.err(2615): No response from server.: 
04-25 06:40:02.372: W/System.err(2615):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.join(MultiUserChat.java:498)
04-25 06:40:02.372: W/System.err(2615):     at example.newchat.DoInBackgroundWork.onPostExecute(DoInBackgroundWork.java:95)
04-25 06:40:02.372: W/System.err(2615):     at example.newchat.DoInBackgroundWork.onPostExecute(DoInBackgroundWork.java:1)
04-25 06:40:02.372: W/System.err(2615):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-25 06:40:02.372: W/System.err(2615):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-25 06:40:02.372: W/System.err(2615):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-25 06:40:02.382: W/System.err(2615):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 06:40:02.382: W/System.err(2615):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 06:40:02.382: W/System.err(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-25 06:40:02.382: W/System.err(2615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 06:40:02.392: W/System.err(2615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 06:40:02.392: W/System.err(2615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-25 06:40:02.392: W/System.err(2615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-25 06:40:02.402: W/System.err(2615):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: hey, did you find what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would post some code specifically the part where you setup the room and join it, I don't have enough rep to put this in a comment sorry :(

I get no response from server when I'm loging in using smack if I've got the wrong username.

Can you successfully connect to the server first?